# How to fetch ejs variable from view back to route file

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I am assigning a value for the variable *received* using app.get and sending it to the view.ejs. Then I want to get this assigned value back for my other function app.get.

**From route.ejs (function A)**

```
app.get('/view',function(req,res){
   res.render('testing.ejs', {received:"hello"});
});
```

**From view.ejs**

```
<h2><%= received %></h2>
```

**From route.ejs (function B)**

```
app.get('/sent',function(req,res){
   var receivedmsg = req.query.received;
   console.log(receivedmsg);
});
```

Function B does not work, I am wondering what is the proper syntax to get back the value. I am trying to use that value and store it in a database.

Thanks!

Comment: Yea.... It's more than your syntax that's off. What do you expect `res.req` to be/do? `res` = response; `req` = request. Have you actually looked at the shape of those objects?

Comment: yeah...thanks for pointing that out, it was a mistake. I meant to write req.query instead

Comment: @Andrew do you want to pass that variable as `query` or `params`

Comment: Seems like your problem is just not mapping the variables properly. Everything else seems alright.

Comment: The question is more about how I can successfully pass the <%= received %> back to route.js. =/